# Is there a way to see Azure AD Connect version using Powershell without access to the local servers?

Tags: powershell, azure, azureadconnect

Is there a way to see the Azure AD Connect version using Powershell without access to the local servers that is running the Azure AD Connect client?

Think of it as a simple environment with servers On-premise, syncronizing users to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect client on a server. Now, I want to see the version on the client without accessing the servers or the Office 365 portal. The reason is that we have many clients like this, and need a list of all versions. We can run Powershell towards them at the same time.

Have looked in the the Powershell module AzureAD but no luck in cmdlets.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the MSOnline module!

```
Get-MsolCompanyInformation -TenantId $customer.TenantId | select DisplayName,DirSyncClientMachineName,DirSyncClientVersion
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(Get-Command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\miiserver.exe").FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Comment: In order to run this, I need access to the servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all info from MS365 portal --> Azure AD connect --> Auzre AD Connect health | sync Service
[How to find Azure AD Connect server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CITjo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can determine the version of Azure AD Connect using PowerShell even without direct access to the local servers where Azure AD Connect is installed. You can use the Azure AD PowerShell module to remotely query information about your Azure AD Connect installation. Here's how you can do it:

1. **Install Azure AD PowerShell Module:**
   If you haven't already, you'll need to install the Azure AD PowerShell module on your local machine. You can do this by running the following command in PowerShell as an administrator:

   ```perl
   Install-Module -Name AzureAD
   ```
2. **Connect to Azure AD:**
   After installing the module, you need to connect to your Azure AD account using the following command:

   ```perl
   Connect-AzureAD
   ```
3. **Retrieve Azure AD Connect Version:**
   Once connected, you can use the `Get-AzureADConnectSyncConfiguration` cmdlet to retrieve information about your Azure AD Connect installation, including its version:

   ```perl
   Get-AzureADConnectSyncConfiguration | Select-Object CurrentConnectorVersion
   ```

   The `CurrentConnectorVersion` property will display the version of Azure AD Connect that is currently configured.

Please note that the Azure AD PowerShell module focuses on Azure AD, and while it can provide information about Azure AD Connect, it might not provide as detailed information as querying the local server directly. Additionally, you'll need appropriate permissions to connect to Azure AD using PowerShell and retrieve the required information.

Remember that the Azure AD Connect version can impact various functionalities, so keeping it up to date is important for maintaining security and utilizing the latest features.